# Variable substition in bash command

Tags: bash

I wanted to do variable substitution in the command below but I can't make it work. The command does not get the value of the variable (ORG and ORGADMIN). Any help is appreciated

```
ORG=caveman
ORGUPPERCASE=Caveman

KEY_FILE_NAME=$(kubectl exec ${ORG}-copy-pod -- bash -c 'ls /${ORG}-org-shared/users/${ORGUPPERCASE}OrgAdmin/msp/keystore')
```

Comment: FYI, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself, whereas names with lowercase characters are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to modify behavior of standard utilities; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace: Setting the former overwrites any instance of the latter having the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.

```
KEY_FILE_NAME=$(kubectl exec ${ORG}-copy-pod -- bash -c "ls /${ORG}-org-shared/users/${ORGUPPERCASE}OrgAdmin/msp/keystore")
```

And you can always check your syntax @ [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: Note that this is only safe if you trust your `ORG` value -- if one needs to deal with potentially-malicious values, different techniques are needed (like exporting the variable for expansion by the child process, or using `printf %q` to generate an escaped version of the value).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Do you have an example of those techniques or a reference to that information by chance? Thanks!

Comment: `printf -v org_q '%q' "$ORG"; printf -v orguppercase_q '%q' "$ORGUPPERCASE"; bash -c "ls /${org_q}-org-shared/users/${orguppercase_q}OrgAdmin/msp/keystore"` would be one example. Or `env "ORG=$ORG" "ORGUPPERCASE=$ORGUPPERCASE" -- bash -c '...$ORG...'` (using single-quotes, but placing the value in the environment).